# is it good to store decimal value as varchar in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have to store user credits which can be in decimal format like (10.99, 0.99, etc.). For now i am taking the column field as varchar(100).

what if i use decimal instead of varchar. will it be improving the performance??

Comment: Use the proper datatypes MySQL provides you. They're there for a reason.

Comment: Why would you store them as varchar in the first place?

Comment: i know they are there that is why i am asking. Will it improve performance if so than how much. I got million of records in my table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is: No, it will hurt performance.

The longer answer: VARCHAR fields are variable length, meaning, that the formatting of the database blocks cannot pre-account for the size of the data filling in there. Sure, there's a maximum length of the field, but other than that, you're off worse.

On the other hand, reading a VARCHAR and then interpreting it to fit into a floating point type will cost you. And it introduces new problem possibilities. Try to get all decimals that account for "11.99". Hope you bring the right number of decimal places, because in VARCHAR "11.99" != "11.990".

And then there's indexing. Usually, nobody indexed a decimal field, but on the off chance that you do, an index on a VARCHAR field will require more space.

All in all, it's not a good idea to save something in an unspecific field type. In the DB structure, it's usually considered best practice to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Suprisingly, you can save disk space (and thus IO time) this way.  It really depends on what the decimal values are and if they're going to stay within that range, and you should absolutely check before doing it.

```
select 
  sum(1+len(cast(Cast(your_decimal_value as real) as varchar(50)))) as size_as_varchar,
  size_of_your_decimal_type_in_bytes*count(*) as size_as_decimal
from your_table
```

If size_as_varchar is substantially lower than size_as_decimal, then you may see performance gains for IO bound queries.  The casting CPU cost may cancel out the gains.

So, should you do this?  It depends on your server, your data, how many of these values your queries require casting on, and your boss' tolerence for deviances from best practice... but the answer is probably no.  If you need this, you should use a database that provides row level compression instead of doing hacky things to approximate row level compression.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some situations where you want to store what look like numeric values as character strings.  For instance, in the US 5-digit zip codes look a lot like numbers.  But, the leading zeros are important.  So, they are really labels rather than numbers.  This is a no-brainer; zip codes should be stored as character strings.

In most other cases, you want to store numbers as numbers.  A field called "user credits" suggests that you are doing addition and subtraction on the field.  So, this is also a no-brainer.  If looks like anumber, walks like a number, and quacks like a number . . . store it as a number.

MySQL does make the choice a bit confusing, because it will automatically convert a string to a number, even when the string has extraneous characters after the numeric portion.

If you want the second decimal point stored exactly, then use a fixed-point data type (such as `DECIMAL(5,2)`) rather than a floating point type (such as `float`).