# should i use DECIMAL or VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I created a database with lots of decimal values and stored them all as varchar(11)
So i had "order-by" issues and temporarily fixed the problem with "cast as".
Should i use decimal(3,8) instead of varchar(11) => I mean would me server be faster if I made that change, or would it make no difference?

ALSO - On the php side, a lot of calculations are going on with my varchar values.

Comment: switch to decimal to keep the size down, varchar(11) takes 11 bytes (depending on the encoding) decimal will take 2-4 bytes depending on the encoding. Plus it helps with sanitation, a non number could be put in the varchar field.

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022668/is-it-good-to-store-decimal-value-as-varchar-in-mysql

Comment: `varchar(11)` is not `decimal(3,8)`. `DECIMAL([total digits], [decimals])`. So with `decimal(10, 8)` you can store numbers with 8 decimals and total 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `decimal` instead of `varchar`. It will be faster!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL prefers numerical values to be in a format like `INT` or `DECIMAL` to facilitate mathematical functions and sorting without having to repeatedly cast.

It would probably be a good idea to switch the column type and let MySQL re-cast all the values for you. Just be sure to test this before you apply it to your production data.

PHP doesn't really care about the difference between strings and numbers, it'll cast for you as required.

Answer (score 1):

I would use decimal.... Always. Unless you have a alpha and numeric value go with decimal. Not only is this faster it is considered better in terms of integrity.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

If you are using you values for calculation purposes I would suggest you use decimal so because when string are add with a '+' sigh it has a different effect than when the decimals are added. So i suggest you better go with the decimals

Comment: What is the difference between adding a string using a `+`, and adding a decimal, in PHP?

Comment: For exapmle when you add a string 1 + 1 you can get a result of 11 instead of 2.

Comment: I think you're muddling PHP with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

yes using `decimal` would make it faster (`it takes less space`) as well as it will be easy for you to manipulate data in decimal format.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that `decimal` takes less space. A `varchar` is a variable-width format versus `decimal` which is fixed width.

Comment: Oh doesn't varchar takes specified bytes of memory?

Comment: . . It is complicated.  I think the `decimal` would always occupy 5 bytes (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html).  The varchar would occupy 1 plus the number of digits in the value (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html).  If most values were `0`, for instance, the `varchar` would win out.

Comment: yeah that way `varchar` wins, so thhis depends on situation....